# PHP Access public variable changed in constrict from child class

Tags: php, oop

How can I access a public property in Child class that was set by a Parent class with __construct?

For example:

```
class Parent
{
    protected $pVariableParent = 'no info'; //This have to be set for all classes

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setPVariable(); //Changing the property when class created.
    }

    public function setPVariable(){
        $this->pVariableParent = '123';
    }
}

Class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['info']){
            echo $this->pVariableParent;
        }
    }
}

$pInit = new Parent;
$cInit = new Child;
```

In this state the request `site.php/?info` shows `no info`. But if I call `$this->setPVariable();` from Child, everything works and shows `123`. Why I can't access already changed property from Parent? Is it because when I call the Child class it just reads the properties and methods of all parents but doesn't trigger any construct functions? And what is the best way to do it? Thanx.

Comment: Your classes should not have public variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you overrode the parent constructor, so `setPVariable` is not called in the child constructor.

To extend the parent constructor instead of override:

```
Class Child extends Parent
{
  public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      if(isset($_GET['info']){
        echo $this->pVariableParent;
    }
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/it/keyword.parent.php

Let me try to clarify one point:

> Why I can't access already changed property from Parent?

Because the property is not already changed. You are creating two separate objects; `$pInit` is an instance of the parent class and its property value gets changed in the constructor. `$cInit` is an instance of the child class and its property value is unchanged since you override the constructor and the child class does not change the property value.`$pInit` and `$cInit` are not related (except by type), and they certainly don't influence the internal structure of each other.

Comment: And it does the __construct of the Parent again. Is there a way to not firing the Parent's __construct again in Child classes but just use its property?

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to accomplish then. Maybe you can clarify your question.

Comment: @passwd yes: don't create a `__contruct()` in the child class, without a constructor, the parent's constructor automatically gets called

Comment: I just want to use the property of Parent in its child without calling another function but just taking the already changed property of Parent. And it is already changed because it changes the property by parent's construct.

Comment: That's not really possible then. You can either call the constructor like in my example. Or just call `setPVariable()` in the child constructor. For your example they are basically equivalent. Given your example you could just have the attribute initialized to "123" but I think that because your example is incomplete